# Where is UpdateException in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm porting my old EF6 code to EF Core and I'm encountering the problem where `UpdateException` is not found in the following code:

```
internal void SetErrors(DbUpdateException ex)
{
    databaseErrors.Clear();

    if (!(ex.InnerException is UpdateException) ||
        !(ex.InnerException.InnerException is SqlException))
        return;

    var sqlException = (SqlException)ex.InnerException.InnerException;

    for (int i = 0; i < sqlException.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        var sqlError = sqlException.Errors[i];

        if (databaseErrors.ContainsKey(sqlError.Number))
            continue;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sqlError.Procedure))
        {
            databaseErrors.Add(sqlError.Number, string.Format("{0}: {1}", sqlError.Procedure, sqlError.Message));
        }
        else
        {
            databaseErrors.Add(sqlError.Number, sqlError.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Intellisense suggests `System.Data` so I added that namespace but it is still not found. So where can I find this class?

Comment: `databaseErrors.Clear();` <-- This doesn't look thread-safe to me... and also means that if you get two errors in a row you'll lose all info about the first.

Comment: Also, in my experience the `SqlException.Procedure`  and `SqlError.Procedure` properties are always empty, even when I use procedures - weird.

Comment: Oh, and watch out for `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` vs [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's gone. Removed. Vanished. Replaced. Pining for the fjords. It is a dead exception type. **It is an ex-exception**.

Observe that [the "Applies to" table in the documentation page for `System.Data.UpdateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.updateexception?view=netframework-4.8) says it's only present in .NET Framework 3.5 through 4.8 and **not** .NET Core nor .NET 5+:

[image]

---

[The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException` replaces it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbupdateexception?view=efcore-6.0): the `Entries` collection property is the analog of `UpdateException.StateEntries`.

There is no guarantee that `DbUpdateException.InnerException` will be a `SqlException`. If you do want to check `InnerException` then do it in a loop, rather than only checking 1 or 2 levels deep:

```
static SqlException? GetFirstInnerSqlExceptionOrNull( Exception? ex )
{
    while( ex != null )
    {
        if( ex is SqlException sqlEx ) return sqlEx;
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage (given your code post):

```
internal void SetErrors( DbUpdateException ex )
{
    if( GetFirstInnerSqlExceptionOrNull( ex ) is SqlException sqlEx )
    {
        foreach( SqlError err in sqlEx.Errors )
        {
            // stuff
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: This is an ex-ception!

Comment: @Flater I'm stealing that...

Comment: Have at it. It seemed the perfect addition to your Monty Python reference.